# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I am getting the following error:

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure pa_Calcular_Anticipo, Line 31
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.*

I have tried moving blocks of code and commenting, but I can't seem to find the problem.

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[pa_Calcular_Anticipo] 
(
    @Tipo_Moneda as numeric(18,0), 
    @Dias as numeric(18,2), 
    @Ciudad_Origen as numeric(18,2), 
    @Ciudad_Destino as numeric(18,2),
    @ArregloPropio int=0
)
 AS
Begin
SET NOCOUNT ON
--Declaracion
Declare @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Origen as numeric(18,2)--
Declare @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Destino as numeric(18,2)--
Declare @Monto_Telefono_Destino as numeric(18,2)--
Declare @Monto_Comida_Destino as numeric(18,2)--
Declare @Monto_Propina_Destino as numeric(18,2)--
Declare @Resultado numeric(18,2)
Declare @Taxi_Aeropuerto_Origen numeric(18,2)--
Declare @Taxi_Aeropuerto_Destino numeric(18,2)--
Declare @Taxi_Interno_Destino numeric(18,2)--

--Obtener Data de la Ciudad Destino
Select  @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Destino = Tasa_Aereoportuaria,
        @Monto_Telefono_Destino = monto_telefono,
        @Monto_Comida_Destino = monto_comida,
        @Monto_Propina_Destino = monto_propina,
        @Taxi_Interno_Destino = Tarifa_Taxi_Interno,
        @Taxi_Aeropuerto_Destino = Tarifa_Taxi_Aeropuerto
from dbo.tb_Ciudades 
where cod_ciudad = @Ciudad_Destino

--Obtener data de la ciudad Origen
Select @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Origen = Tasa_Aereoportuaria,
           @Taxi_Aeropuerto_Origen = monto_telefono,
from dbo.tb_Ciudades 
where cod_ciudad=@Ciudad_Destino

-- Opciones 
IF (@ArregloPropio = 1) --anticipo = si, Traslado = no
              --Monto Calculado = ((Comida + Teléfono + propina) * Días) + (Tasa Aeropuerto Origen + Tasa Aeropuerto Destino)
    BEGIN
        set @resultado = ((@Monto_Comida_Destino + @Monto_Telefono_Destino + @Monto_Propina_Destino) *@Dias) + ( @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Origen +@Tasa_Aeropuerto_Destino)
    END

IF (@ArregloPropio = 2) --Anticipo es igual a “No” y Traslado es igual “No”
    BEGIN
        set @resultado = 0
    END

IF (@ArregloPropio = 3) --Anticipo es igual a “Si” y Traslado es igual “Arreglo Propio”
              --Monto Calculado = ((Comida + Teléfono + propina) * Días) + (Tasa Aeropuerto Origen + Tasa Aeropuerto Destino) + ((Monto Traslados Internos) * Días) + (Traslados Aeropuerto Origen + Traslados Aeropuerto Destino) 
    BEGIN
        set @resultado = ((@Monto_Comida_Destino + @Monto_Telefono_Destino + @Monto_Propina_Destino) *@Dias) + ( @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Origen +@Tasa_Aeropuerto_Destino) + ((@Taxi_Interno_Destino) *Dias) + ( Taxi_Aeropuerto_Destino + @Taxi_Aeropuerto_Origen ) 
    END

IF (@ArregloPropio = 4) --Anticipo es igual a “No” y Traslado es igual “Arreglo Propio”
              --Monto Calculado = (Monto Traslados Internos * Días) + (Tasa Aeropuerto Origen + Tasa Aeropuerto Destino)
    BEGIN
        set @resultado = ((@Taxi_Interno_Destino) *Dias) +( @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Origen +@Tasa_Aeropuerto_Destino)
    END

IF (@ArregloPropio = 5) --Anticipo es igual a “Si” y Traslado es igual “Servicio”
              --Monto Calculado = ((Comida + Teléfono + Propina) * Días) + (Monto Traslados Internos * Días) + (Tasa Aeropuerto Origen + Tasa Aeropuerto Destino)
    BEGIN
        set @resultado = ((@Monto_Comida_Destino + @Monto_Telefono_Destino + @Monto_Propina_Destino) *@Dias) + ((@Taxi_Interno_Destino) *Dias) + ( @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Origen +@Tasa_Aeropuerto_Destino)
    END

IF (@ArregloPropio = 6) --Busqueda por Codigo
    BEGIN
        set @resultado = 0
    END

select @resultado as Monto_Calculado  
end
```

Comment: You have an extra comma here: `... monto_telefono, from dbo.tb_Ciudades ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have extra comma, here:

```
Select  @Tasa_Aeropuerto_Origen = Tasa_Aereoportuaria,
        @Taxi_Aeropuerto_Origen = monto_telefono,
from dbo.tb_Ciudades 
where cod_ciudad=@Ciudad_Destino
```

Comment: Thanks! I Was going nuts trying to find what i had missed.

Comment: You're welcome, I got a fair share of those errors myself :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last comma from your second select `@Taxi_Aeropuerto_Origen = monto_telefono,`